# Is there a way to make Chinese characters on Windows 10 larger, more readable or choose a different font?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, language, language-pack

[image: filename]

The characters are too small, weird-looking and just hard to read.
Is there a way to make the default font more readable, i.e. change it, turn it into a true-type or something?

Answer (score 1):

For web browsing you can install the [Hanzisize](https://rjpeterson.github.io/hanzisize-about/) browser extension. It allows you enlarge Chinese characters without changing the size of other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following methods to change the size of text, images, and apps in Windows 10.

To change your display in Windows 10, select **Start**  > **Settings**  > **Ease of Access** > **Display**. To make only the text on your screen larger, adjust the slider under **Make text bigger**. To make everything larger, including images and apps, choose an option from the drop-down menu under **Make everything bigger**.